# How to Update the iOS 9 app use latest Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

My project is currently compatible with iOS8 (Swift 1.2) version. 
It uses the Facebook SDK.
And few days ago I have got the message from it:

> Action required for your iOS 9 app Update your app to use Facebook SDK
>   for iOS v4.6 or v3.24 to support iOS 9.

Does anyone has already experience with this update? I mean what exactly do I need to do to update Facebook SDK in project. Like it says I need to:

1. Download the new SDK for iOS: v4.6 or v3.24
2. Update your app's plist ..

.. but do I need to replace imported Facebook SDA frameworks
    or if it says: "The SDK automatically loads its framework and
    resource dependencies." i do not need to do this?

or I just need to add this and that's it:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>        
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You should always update your SDK to the latest version. This will not happen automatically. Also you should prefer the new 4.x SDK over the old 3.x SDK. But note that the SDK changed completely from 3.x to 4.x so you'll have to rewrite some Facebook-related code on your app.